# How to get xml as response in struts2

Tags: java, xml, struts2

I am trying to get a response in javascript of type xml in strurts2. 
In my action class I am creating a xml and I am trying to get it at java script. 
My code at action class -

```
public String populateXML(){
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    String root = "menuTree";
    File file = new File(this.getServletRequest().getRealPath("/xml/xmlmenutree2.xml"));

    documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document1 = documentBuilder.newDocument();

    Element rootElement = null;
    rootElement = document1.createElement(root);
    document1.appendChild(rootElement);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document1);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);

    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This will create a xml file in my disk. and in my javascript i am accessing it like --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
    xmlUrl : 'xml/xmlmenutree2.xml' 

};
    $('#xmlMenuTree').xmltree(options);
}
```

where xmlMenuTree is my div id at jsp.
and strurts xml-

```
<action name="fileManagement" class="com.amit.MyAction" method="populateXML">
  <result name="success" type="tiles">filemanagement</result>
</action>
```

This is working fine. But I actually wanted the xml to be set at response instead of saving it in my disk.
Is it possible to make a setup in strurts2? thank u in advance .
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml in response object and access in view layer by proper tags...simple. 
i think this might save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Action:

```
  public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    //Generate xml like InputStream and put it here
    private InputStream myXmlStream;
```

Action definition:

```
<action name="MyAction" class="mypackage.MyAction">
  <result type="stream">
     <!-- Struts will take InputStream from this variable and send it as response-->
    <param name="myXmlStream">text/plain</param>
    <!-- Set fake filename-->
    <param name="contentDisposition">filename="xmlmenutree2.xml"</param>
  </result>
</action
```

Comment: Not sure what the `myXmlStream` param is, but it wouldn't be text/plain if it's an XML doc, it'd be either `text/xml` or `application/xml` or something--for `contentType`. `inputName` sets the stream property name, and defaults to `inputStream`.